# Unable to emit same state when new data gets added using equatable in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to emit same state with different set of data using equatable. But, somehow the state doesn't get emitted the second time when next 5 records are added in the list.

It would be great if someone could help.

This is how I am emitting post:

```
loadedState = LoadedPosts(
                      now: DateTime.now(),
                      post: List.from(postDetailsFilteredPostResponse, growable: false),
                          newCount: 0,
                          friends: List.from(postFriendsResponse, growable: false),
                          likes: List.from(postLikesResponse, growable: false),
                          comments:List.from(postCommentsResponse, growable: false),
                          photos: List.from(postPhotosResponse, growable: false),
                          userDetail: userDetail);

emit(loadedState);
```

This is the state class:

```
 abstract class PostState extends Equatable{
    @override
    List<Object?> get props => [];
}
class LoadedPosts extends PostState{
  List<Post> post = List<Post>.filled(5, Post(postId: ''));
  final List<User>? friends;
  final List<Images> photos;
  final List<UserLikes> likes;
  final List<UserComments> comments;
  final User? userDetail;
  final int newCount;
  final DateTime now;


  LoadedPosts({
    required this.post,
    required this.friends,
    required this.photos,
    required this. likes,
    required this.comments,
    required this.newCount,
    required this.now,
    this.userDetail });
 

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [now, post];
}
```

Comment: Your new state should have different data than previous state. if you're trying to emit same state with same set of data than bloc won't emits. or else try to have timestamp in model any raise state with current timestamp everytime.

Comment: the data is different only in the list, can try adding timestamp

Comment: for the list it will be different but for state model still its list and same. it won't compare whole list items with previous. so better to have timestamp.

Comment: added the timestamp to the state, but still doesn't work. Updated the code in the question.

Comment: Instead DateTime object, take it as int and have value as miliseconds that will be always unique

Comment: I did try adding 5 hours to the current date time to make it unique, but even that didn't work.

Comment: how are you adding items to `postDetailsFilteredPostResponse`? Like from previous state.

Comment: I have filled it from another list which was cached before after the first call was made.  The first call fetched first 5 records and displayed it on the UI, another call was made to cache all records meanwhile.  After that, when user scrolls around 90% of the screen, another call gets fired to fetch next 5 records from the cache. postDetailsFilteredPostResponse = List.from(postDetailsPostResponse.sublist(postsLength,postsLength+sizePerPage ),growable: false);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Model as below, have your timestamp as int and assign unique timestamp value ( Mili-seconds ) every-time when you emit.

```
abstract class PostState extends Equatable {
    @override
    List<Object?> get props => [];
} 

class LoadedPosts extends PostState {
    final List<Post> post;
    final List<User>? friends;
    final List<Images> photos;
    final List<UserLikes> likes;
    final List<UserComments> comments;
    final User? userDetail;
    final int newCount;
    final int now; // have this as ( int )


LoadedPosts({
    required this.post,
    required this.friends,
    required this.photos,
    required this. likes,
    required this.comments,
    required this.newCount,
    required this.now,
    this.userDetail });


    @override
    List<Object?> get props => [now, post];
}
```

Have the value like this:

```
LoadedPosts(now: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks! but doesn't work. not sure what is it the issue now. It just doesn't emit the state again.

Comment: Thanks for your time! it does work now, I made a mistake of creating a new bloc instance.

Answer (score 0):

Make all the lists growable: false in your state class. So when you are creating a state object, pass the list as follows.

`List.from([1,2,3], growable: false);`

now, you won't be able to add any elements to same list object. Every time, you will have to do `List.from([...oldList, ...newItems], growable:false);`

This will make sure your data is immutable and state is emitted.

Comment: I tried the same, but didn't work. modified the code accordingly. Maybe there is something else which is incorrect, not sure.

Comment: Thanks, there was some other issue with the bloc instance. Now,it works.